# winappdriver get Data from System.Data.DataRowView

Tags: c#, winforms, winappdriver

I am writing an UI Test for a Windows Forms application, up untill now I was able to extract the nessesary information for the Tests with the Windows Kit inspect tool

**The Inspector Tool**
[image]

now my problem is, I got the following list, but I cant get the text of the list item. Normally the text of an element is the property Name but in this list its just "System.Data.DataRowView"

**The List in the UI**
[image]

for anyone corious, this is how im getting the element (C#)

```
WindowsElement element = driver.FindElementByName("System.Data.DataRowView");
```

and this is how it looks like in the Debugger:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out it is not possible, this issiue on the github repository describes it:

https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver/issues/1475

The only workarounds are screnshoting and extracting the Text with OCR